# Convert RTF into XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, etl, rtf, data-transform

I have a rich text document(.rtf or .doc) that has lot of data elements which needs to be read and converted into structured data objects either XML or Json. These docs have certain formats in terms of data. Are there any libraries that i can use to convert using java. DO anyone have come across this type of scenario?

Has anyone tried Apache POI or Apache Tika to convert into XML

Comment: Why not find the right tool first, and then figure out how to invoke that?  Because this sounds 100% like a job for https://pandoc.org/

Comment: Hi Mike, We would need to do this in systematic way as part of our batch jobs. Hence we have to chose one of programming technique either java, perl, shell etc

Comment: if you need this as an automated step then doing the conversion _in_ java is kind of crazy. It would make far more sense to call pandoc in a shell script, and then have that same shell script then run whatever java program you write to further deal with the XML (if you even need one, because there are standalone XLST transformers that you can use, too, like saxon etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'd break this task into two parsers and two serializers

1. Parse rtf to java model
2. Parse doc to java model
3. Serialize java model to xml
4. Serialize java model to json

For 1&2 its pretty standard to use [POI](https://poi.apache.org/). 
For 3&4 you have many more options, a popular option would be [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try parsing doc to java using POI. Agree once we have Java model it is easy to covert into xml/json.

Comment: I did try using POI but all of that coverts into a String and looks like we may have to handcode string conversion into structured java object. Any idea on how that could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at [RTF Parser Kit](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit) which you can use to populate a Java data structure suitable for further processing or persistence.